# Viewpager to read different files?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to use a view page to read an indeterminate number of files, i have an activity that creates a person's profile and saves the data, and now i need one that uses ViewPager to access the files with only a swipe, i have the layout created and i can load a single file to it and i have a list of all the files in that directory the only thing i need is to implement that in a viewpager in order to switch between my Profiles, i don't know how to use ViewPager can someone please help me out in this? providing an example code, or a useful link that goes according to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Example of using ViewPager with fragments](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using)

[Example of using ViewPager without fragments](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.viewpager/src/de/vogella/android/viewpager/ViewPagerActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement *FragmentStatePagerAdapter*
which is best for paging across a collection of objects for which the number of pages is undetermined. It destroys fragments as the user navigates to other pages, minimizing memory usage.

Check this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I find this useful, gonna check it out today and try to implement is thanks